# Convert double to int inaccuracy (1 off)

Tags: c

I have the following situation that gives me 27 instead of 28:

```
double d = 0.35;
int i = 80;

int ans = (int)(d * i);

printf("%d", ans);
```

But I get the right answer if I use this:

```
int ans = (int)(0.35 * 80);
printf("%d", ans);
```

or:

```
double ans = d * i;
printf("%d", (int) ans);
```

Can someone explain why the first situation is 1 off and the others work?

I did some research and people say that double stores a number like 28 as 27.999..., but I'm confused as in what scenarios this would occur in.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is about C, not C++. As for the question itself, I cannot reproduce your problem. I get 28 in all three cases on gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1.

Comment: [I try it in ideone, and it returns 28](https://ideone.com/6J4yMm). What compiler and platform are you using?

Comment: Helpful reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: I get also 27 for first case

Comment: @A.ANoman And what compiler are you using?

Comment: Must be a compiler issue.  My compiler returns 28 for both situations.

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.9.3 on eclipse windows

Comment: " I'm confused as in what scenarios this would occur in."  - this one

Comment: @AntonH GNU GCC compiler mingw32-gcc

Comment: Value of `0.35` does not have an exact binary floating-point representation. So, your `double d = 0.35;` is not really `0.35` at all, but rather something like `0.34999999999999998`. The rest follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value of `0.35` does not have an exact binary floating-point representation. So on typical platforms using IEEE 754-based floating-point support, your `double d = 0.35;` is not really `0.35` at all, but rather something like `0.34999999999999998` - a value that in this case happens to be *smaller* than the original `0.35`. The rest follows: multiplication produces less than `28`, which gets truncated to `27` by your `(int)`. End of story.

If someone is getting `28` from this example it probably means that their compiler uses a different floating-point evaluation model, in which the original `0.35` might be represented either *precisely* or as some value slightly *greater* than `0.35` (say, `0.35000000000012` or something like that). Compilers that optimized the calculations and performed them at compile time also fall into that category.

The difference between

```
int ans = (int)(d * i);
printf("%d", ans);
```

and

```
double ans = d * i;
printf("%d", (int) ans);
```

might easily be caused by the compiler literally storing the intermediate result in a `double` variable `ans` in the second case.

The actual multiplication might be performed in a high-precision floating-point register of the CPU (whose precision is higher than `double`). In the first case the result gets stored directly into an `int`. In the second case it is first converted to lower-precision `double` and only then that `double` gets converted to `int`. This extra intermediate conversion to `double` can easily change the result.

Comment: Your answer does not explain why `int ans=(int)(d * i)` differs from `double ans = d * i; int(ans)`. Isn't `d` implicitly promoted to `double` in the latter case?

Comment: So if ans = 0.35 * 80, 28.000 would be stored into ans and not 27.999... Right?

Comment: @Rig: No one knows what would be stored. It depends on what approach your compiler takes when calculating this expression. Compile it and look at the machine code to see what your compiler decided to do - that's the only way to know. But don't take it as absolute truth, since tomorrow your compiler might start behaving differently.

Comment: @AnT, Ok. Regarding the second half of your solution: just to confirm, the intermediate double converts the slightly off value to the full value of 28.

Comment: @Rig: Might be. Or it might convert it to a slightly off value of `28.000000012`. The end result after truncation to `int` is still the same - `28`.

Comment: @AnT, what do you recommend to avoid this kind of problem consistently in the future?